# setInterval can't be stopped by clearInterval when use setState in React

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, clearinterval

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    setState({ ...state, on: !state.on });
    let tog = state.on;
    console.log("first" + tog);
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (tog) {
        console.log(tog);
      } else clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDmE4.png)
this one will not be able to stop even the tog is false;
however if I don't use state, change to a variable it will not happen,
it is so weird for me, I need some help;

```
let flag = true;
  const handleClick = () => {
    flag = !flag;
    console.log("first" + flag);
   const interval = setInterval(()=>{
     if(flag){
       console.log(flag);
     }else(clearInterval(interval))
   },1000)
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React will create new `handleClick` on every re-renders, and there will be different setIntervals,

```
const intvl = useRef(null);

const handleClick = () => {
    intvl.current = setInterval(() => { //now interval is not changing on every fn recreation
        .....

   clearInterval(intvl.current);
}
```

[check this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sydsph)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `Effect` to handle intervals, something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId
    if (state.on) { 
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(state.on)
      }, 1000)
      return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
  }, [state.on])

  const handleClick = () => {
    setState({ ...state, on: !state.on });
  };
```

[working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-en5smj)

Comment: Thank you and @Kalhan, both are correct, I like your solution better but he was the first to comment, haha